# Searching for related events in log file

Tags: search, logging

Let's say I have a log file, which contains lines describing certain events. E.g.:

```
15.03.2014 (14:23) Thing #25 deleted, user @david, session #45
15.03.2014 (15:00) Thing #26 created, user @alex, session #54
...
```

I can easily extract standalone events using `grep` - it works fine even if I don't know all the information about an event.

But I want to make a step further and investigate related events. Consider following lines in log:

```
15.03.2014 (14:23) Thing #25 created, user @david, session #45
... 
17.03.2014 (15:00) Thing #25 deleted, user @david, session #54
```

I want to search for `Thing #X created, user @Y, session #Z` events only if they are succeeded by `Thing #X deleted, user @Y, session #M` event, where M and Z are different.

Of course I can do that in 5-10 lines of code: search events of the first type, take all succeeding lines, search events of the second type, filter.

But maybe there is some tool for this and I will be reinventing the wheel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perl is a very powerful tool for these sorts of tasks, and can handle it with a one-liner, something like this:

```
cat txt | perl -n -e 'if (m^Thing #(\d+).*? (created|deleted).*? user @(\S+),.*? session #(\d+)^) { my $id = "$3.$1"; if ($2 eq "created") { @db{$id} = [$4,$_] } else { if (exists($db{$id}) && $db{$id}[0] != $4) { print $db{$id}[1]."$_" } delete @db{$id} } }'
```

Here's the same thing as a shell script, for ease of reading:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

while (<>) {
  if (m^Thing #(\d+).*? (created|deleted).*? user @(\S+),.*? session #(\d+)^) {
     my $id = "$3.$1";
     if ($2 eq "created") {
        @db{$id} = [$4,$_]
     } else {
        if (exists($db{$id}) && $db{$id}[0] != $4) {
            print $db{$id}[1]."$_"
        }
        delete @db{$id};
     }
  }
}
```

This will print out the create/destroy line pairs where a given user created and destroyed a particular Thing with a different session id.

Note the script assumes that 'Thing' identifiers are user-specific, and treats cases where one user creates Thing X and another destroys Thing X as separate Things (if this is not true and users share Things, change $id to "$1"). It also assumes Things are destroyed at most once per create (if multiple deletes per create are possible, remove the delete line). Obviously I don't have your actual input file, so you may need to adjust the regexp to match the actual format.

This approach may be notably better than performing multiple searches as suggested in the OP, because it does everything in a single pass through the log with no temporary files; thus it may be more efficient/appropriate for very large log files. The memory utilization scales with the number of 'Things' that are live at any point, so should be reasonable unless your log has a huge number of very long-lived Things.

Comment: Thanks! This is a good approach and does the job in O(n). But I wondered if there are tools which implement this algorithm or were designed to handle this kind of "queries"

Comment: @madfriend - Perl IS a tool that was originally designed specifically to handle this type of textual processing. The "query" interface just happens to look like somewhat like an imperative program :-)